# I need to lock the user to make max two orders (forms), and the second one is not locking on ASP MVC 3 C#

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-2, controller

thanks for reading my post, i am from yesterday trying with this code to lock the function "secundario" and bring always the same info until i totalize or cancel that order.

Is working fine with "index" Function, but not with "secundario" function

```
[AuthorizeRoles(Modulo = "4310")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            /* Lot of Code Here */

            var pedido_1 = dc.SAFACTs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.CodUsua == User.Identity.Name && b.SAFACT_01.Estado == "0");

            if (pedido_1 != null)
            {
                Session["pedido1"] = pedido_1;

                /* Lot of Code Here */

            }

            /* If order "pedido1" does not exist, we create a new order */

            return View(pedido_1); //Load the view with the data and here works the lock. View Data with the data of pedido_1 until the user totalize or cancel this order

        }

[AuthorizeRoles(Modulo = "4310")]
        public ActionResult secundario()
        {
            if (Session["pedido1"] != null) //I check if the first order "pedido1" exists, if exists i do the second order
            {
                /* Lot of Code Here */

                var pedido_2 = dc.SAFACTs.Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault(b => b.CodUsua == User.Identity.Name && b.SAFACT_01.Estado == "0");

                if (Session["pedido2"] != null)
                {
                    pedido_2 = (PRINCIPAL.Areas.VENTAS.Models.SAFACT)Session["pedido2"];
                    //Session["pedido2"] = pedido_2;
                }

                if (pedido_2 != null)
                {
                    /* Lot of Code Here */
                }

                /* If order "pedido2" does not exist, we create a new order */

                return View(pedido_2); /* Load the view with the data and here DOES NOT work the lock and i can make n orders 
                I should View Data with the data of pedido_2 until the user totalize or cancel this order
                */
            }
            else // If first order "pedido1" does not exist i redirect the user to index function
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "PROG_4310"); //Redirect to Index
            }

        }
```

If you wish have a look at full code you can refer at this question i did yesterday -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217172/wish-to-lock-the-user-to-two-forms-as-a-max-and-finish-both-forms-so-he-can-do)

Thanks in Advance, any help would be appreciated

Comment: As long as this code snipped won't compile for us anyway, it would help a lot if you would rewrite it in english :) Also, code is not optimal even without understanding its purpose - first you load value to pedido_2 from context, then you assign value from session - what is the point loading from database in first place?

Comment: @Giedrius that is trying to avoid a third order without finishing fist two, that is not working, i am trying any ways to do that, that would be a "because"